# Gas Oven Stove Will Not Ignite

Tags: appliances, gas, oven, troubleshooting

My wife reported that our GE profile JGS968SEK1SS would not heat. I removed the igniter and it is reporting 99.1 Ohms for continuity, which seems fine to me. What other troubleshooting options do I have?

Comment: Does it receive fuel?

Comment: Can you light the burners for the cooktop? Do you smell gas when trying to run the oven? Are the jets clean for the oven? Do you see a spark or ticking sound from the igniter?

Answer (score 1):

While the igniter may have continuity, it must get hot enough to 'trip' the gas valve to open (usually by drawing enough current).  Does it glow when energized?  If not, the problem may be upstream at the control board, or a wire may have burnt through.

See the video and 5 steps for [trouble shooting this oven here](http://www.repairclinic.com/RepairHelp/How-To-Fix-A-Range-Stove-Oven/18-3-857940-/GE-Oven-won-t-turn-on--JGS968SEK1SS)